# setup.py install show only the folders

Tags: python, setup.py, pypi

I am trying to make a library for pypi in python so I made setup.py file. 
I uploaded it after looking at some tutorials but when I am trying to install it via `pip install pyravendb` I only get an empty folder.

Tried to install it directly from `python setup.py install.` 
Again getting only an pyravendb empty folder.

my setup.py file

```
from distutils.core import setup

    setup(
        name='pyravendb',
        packages=['pyravendb'],
        version='1.0.1',
        description='This is the official python client for RavenDB document database',
        author='Idan Haim Shalom',
        author_email='my email',
        url='https://github.com/IdanHaim/RavenDB-Python-Client/',
        download_url='https://github.com/IdanHaim/RavenDB-Python-Client/tarball/1.0.1',
        keywords='ravendb pyravendb database',
        license='GNU',
        requires=
        [
            'pycrypto',
            'requests',
            'Inflector'
        ],
        zip_safe=False,
    )
```

Comment: What does your project structure look like?

Comment: you can see it in github
https://github.com/IdanHaim/RavenDB-Python-Client/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project appears to have the following structure:

```
pyravendb/
  connection/
  custom_exceptions/
  d_commands/
  data/
  hilo/
  store/
  tests/
  tools/
```

Add your setup.py file to the project root folder and change `packages` to include each module/folder you want to include in your distribution. You can explicitly state all modules to be packaged as follows:

```
packages=[
        'pyravendb',
        'pyravendb.connection',
        'pyravendb.custom_exceptions',
        'pyravendb.d_commands',
        'pyravendb.data',
        'pyravendb.hilo',
        'pyravendb.store',
        # and so on....
],
```

Alternatively, you can use `setuptools` and import `find_packages` and then use `packages=find_packages(),` to automatically use all packages in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I manage to find the correct answer. like PRNDL suggested but with a little  less work.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
```

and in the packages add find_packages() method to find all my packages

```
setup(
    name='pyravendb',
    packages=find_packages(),
```

Because my project structure have multi sub directory packages I had to include all of them in my setup.py that`s why my first attempt was  a failure.
Doing like the above solved my problem without write all my packages name

Comment: I originally had ``find_packages()`` included in my answer, but you were using distutils and was unsure if that was necessary or not.